# Row update count of OBIEE12c administration tool does not work

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am trying to update row count of physical table of obiee12c administration tool, however I am getting the following error.

[NQODBC][SQL_STATE:HY000][nQSError:10058] A general error has occurred.

Database version: Oracle Database 19c
Obiee version: 12.2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround can fix the issue.

1. Go to the connection pool of physical layer of OBIEE administration tool.
2. Double Click on connection pool.
3. Provide the full database description in the data source name.
   for example:

`(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ********)(PORT = ****))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ******)))`